# Drush fails with "PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function decode_entities()"

Tags: 7, drush

My drush installation does not work anymore on an Debian Vserver. I get always the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function `decode_entities()`
>       in /usr/share/drush/includes/drush.inc on line 1619

I have drush-6.2.0.0 installed there and can't reproduce what caused the error. Any suggestions?

Comment: What drupal version is it? And what command you tried to invoke? From which dir? Looks like somehow unicode.inc wasn't loaded.

Comment: @Mołot I am using Drupal 7, I tried from Drupal's root dir. The error occurs with almost any command. For example with `drush update something`

Comment: Magic. Is the unicode.inc present?